# DataTables Not Applying per page filtering

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I'm attempting to use [DataTables Server Side Processing](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side)

**Currently I'm getting 1000 rows back (as display) even though the display is set to 10, 25, etc**

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#paginatedTableSS').dataTable( {
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "ajax": "script.php"
      } );
} );
```

script.php:

```
$i = 0;
$test = array();
$test['draw'] = 1;
$test['recordsTotal'] = 200000;
$test['recordsFiltered'] = 8;
$test['data'] = array();
while($i<=20){
  array_push($test['data'], ['test1 ' . $i, 'test2 ' . $i, 'test3 ' . $i, 'test4 ' . $i]);
  $i=$i+1;
}
echo json_encode($test);
```

My ultimate goal is to pass along `start` to the script so the script can use that to give the correct data back. But currently I need to fix the above before moving forward I think. But I'm not sure what's wrong with it or how to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

`aaData` seems to indicate that you're using the legacy datatables. If that's the case, you're missing `iTotalRecords`, `iTotalDisplayRecords` and `sEcho`.

```
$test['iTotalRecords'] = count($test['aaData']);
$test['iTotalDisplayRecords'] = count($test['aaData']);
$test['Echo'] = $_REQUEST['sEcho'];
```

see http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side

if you're not using the legacy datatables you need to use `data`, `records` and `recordsFiltered` instead (as referenced in your link)

**Edit**

The reason your table is displaying 1000 rows is because that's the # of rows you're returning. Use the `length` and `start` parameters to determine which rows to return i.e

```
$start = (isset($_REQUEST['start']) && is_numeric($_REQUEST['start']))
    ? $_REQUEST['start'] : 0;

$length = (isset($_REQUEST['length']) && is_numeric($_REQUEST['length']))
    ? $_REQUEST['length'] : 100;

$test = array('data'=>array(), 'recordsTotal', 'draw', 'recordsFiltered');

for($i=$start; $i<=$length; $i++) {
  array_push($test['data'], array('id'=>$i,'date'=>$i,'status'=>$i,'options'=>$i));  
}

$test['recordsTotal'] = 200000;
$test['draw'] = 1;
$test['recordsFiltered'] = count($test['data']);
echo json_encode($test);
```

Comment: You were right that I was trying to mix legacy and new, I've fixed that and updated my problem above. The core issue still exists.

Comment: @AndrewWilson your javascript is still using legacy syntax

Comment: I don't see a new syntax for Columns, is that what you're referring to?

Comment: What should the jQuery look like, because I can't get it to pass length/start by just adding `"length":52,` to it

Comment: If I remove serverSide I can get length/start to push. So it's only when I'm using serverSide